# How to auto apply changes changes on custom plugin (resource) in Drupal 8

Tags: rest, drupal-8

I'm new to drupal 8 (coming from drupal 7) and I'm trying to develop custom rest resources. So far, following https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview I have my resource running but everytime I make a change I have to uninstall and reinstall my module or use REST UI to re-save configuration of the resoruce. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps here I was able to solve this problem:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914